# How to get logstash to store all of the words from one field as an array in another field

Tags: logstash

I am struggling with the filters in Logstash.

I am trying to take a well structured json stream (I am using a twitter feed for test data) and augment the data. One of our needs is to take an existing field, such as message, and store all of the unique tokens (in this case simple space delimited words).

In the long run we would like to be able to use elastic search analyzers to break down the message into normalized chunks (using stemming, stopwords, toLower, etc...)

The desired goal is to take something like:
{
    "@timestamp":"2016-10-12T19:01:33.000Z",
    "message":"The quickest Brown fox",
    ...
}

and get something like:
{
    "@timestamp":"2016-10-12T19:01:33.000Z",
    "message":"The quickest Brown fox",
    "tokens":["The", "quickest", "Brown", "fox"],
    ...
}

and ultimately like this:
{
    "@timestamp":"2016-10-12T19:01:33.000Z",
    "message":"The quickest Brown fox",
    "tokens":["quick", "brown", "fox"],
    ...
}

I feel like I am pounding my head against a wall. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The tokens array is exactly what ES produces, indexes and stores when you ask it to analyze your `message` field. I don't quite get why you need to create a new field out of those tokens? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily using the mutate filter:

```
   mutate {
         split => {"message" => " "}
    }
```

This tells LS to split the field denoted with "message" using the separator assigned in the hash, in this case a whitespace.

Test:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf2/
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
The quickest Brown Fox
{
       "message" => [
        [0] "The",
        [1] "quickest",
        [2] "Brown",
        [3] "Fox"
    ],
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-10-13T13:46:20.509Z",
          "host" => "pandaadb"
}
```

Result is the message field being an array of elements.

Alternatively, you can also copy the message field into a tokens field before splitting it. It needs to be done in 2 steps for this to work, for example to write it into a tokens field:

```
 mutate {
         add_field => {"tokens" => "%{message}" }
    }

    mutate {
        split => { "tokens" => " "}
    }
```

The first mutate adds a new field called token with the content of the message field, while the second one splits the token field by space.

Hope that helps,

Artur